# reading CSV file into julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

When I try to import a csv file into a Julia DataFrame as descibed in [this blogpost](https://towardsdatascience.com/read-csv-to-data-frame-in-julia-programming-lang-77f3d0081c14) I get unexpected results.

`DataFrame()` puts each CSV.Row into a cell instead of each field. CSV.jl doesn't seem to be the problem, since the CSV.Row objects are correct. Does somebody see what I'm missing here?

**example.csv**

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
2,3,5
0,1,1
```

```
using CSV
using DataFrames

DataFrame(CSV.File("example.csv"))
```

**result**

| x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CSV.Row: (col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 3) | CSV.Row: (col1 = 2, col2 = 3, col3 = 5) | CSV.Row: (col1 = 0, col2 = 1, col3 = 1) |

**expected result**

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |

**Edit**

I was using:

CSV v0.8.3

DataFrames v0.13.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the latest DataFrames.jl 0.22.5 and CSV.jl 0.8.3. Under them I get what you ask for:

```
julia> str = """col1,col2,col3
       1,2,3
       2,3,5
       0,1,1""";

julia> DataFrame(CSV.File(IOBuffer(str)))
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ col1   col2   col3  
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      2      3
   2 │     2      3      5
   3 │     0      1      1
```

Comment: Thnx, for the quick reply. My DataFrames version was indeed the problem.